# On Javascript, how to re-arrange an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have the following javascript array *var rows*.

```
[
    { email: 'user1@example.com' },
    { email: 'user2@example.com' }
]
```

Of which, I wanted to make it just...

```
[
    'user1@example.com',
    'user2@example.com'
]
```

So, I tried to loop it using ***forEach***

```
rows.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log('entry:');
    console.log(entry.email);
});
```

However, I am stuck with that.

```
entry:
user1@example.com
entry:
user2@example.com
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note: You already have the question tagged with `node.js` and `javascript`, so they don't need to be listed again in the title.

Comment: Alright. Noted Jonathan.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var newArray = oldArray.map(function (obj) {
    return obj.email;
});
```

Comment: I think this would be the answer. However, node.js is throwing. TypeError: Object #<RowDataPacket> has no method 'map'. Anyway, that's a different problem that I need to solve.

Comment: Would it be correct, if I add the .map answer inside the forEach loop?

Comment: See if you can do something like `Array.prototype.splice.call(this, rows).map(...);`, I don't know what `RowDataPacket` is but maybe a slice works. Otherwise you have to loop with foreach and store the values in a new array.

Answer (score 2):

here is your solution

```
var rows =[
    { email: 'user1@example.com' },
    { email: 'user2@example.com' }
];
var yop = [];
rows.forEach(function(entry) {
    yop.push(entry.email);
});

console.log(yop);
```

Comment: This would work although there is no need for the `new` keyword.